# Get authentication from parent web application using webmatrix from MVC Core app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core, webmatrix

Is there any way I can have a MVC Core application sitting under an older MVC 4.7 application and have it use the same authentication?  The older application is using WebMatrix for authentication which is outdated.  I would rather not have to change this, but if I have to are there any systems that do work Across both platforms?  The child application sits in the same domain as the parent.